# How to reset form state in angularjs2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to reset form state from dirty/touched in angular?

I am learning angular2 now and form a form that have validation.

In the tutorial,

```
<form *ngIf="booleanFlag">..</form>
```

to reset the form state. The tutorial said there is better solution but I am not be able to find it yet. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to reset it on button click then try input `type="reset"`

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
```

Comment: What if i wanna reset after click add button which type is just a button